# python export multiple prometheus registries with one port

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, python-requests, prometheus, metrics

i need your help in python pleaaaaz

i have python script with Gauge family metric to export jenkins metrics to prometheus with two exporter classes :
jenkinsCollector and PollScm.
here is some of the code :

```
 class JenkinsCollector:
     def __init__(self, jenkinsInstances):
// some code
     def collect(self):
// some code for gauge metric
 class pollScm:
     def __init__(self, jenkinsInstances):
// some code
     def collect(self):
// some code for gauge metric
            registrynode = CollectorRegistry()
            registrynode.register(JenkinsCollector(
              jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
            start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registrynode)
          
            registryscm = CollectorRegistry()
            registryscm.register(pollScm(
              jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
            start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registryscm)
```

the export works for only one metric !! either jenkinsCollector or PollScm **because they use the same port** !!
so to make it work, i have to comment either this part

```
 registrynode = CollectorRegistry()
            registrynode.register(JenkinsCollector(
              jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
            start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registrynode)
```

Or this part

```
registryscm = CollectorRegistry()
            registryscm.register(pollScm(
              jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
            start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registryscm)
```

I tried to find a way in python to use multiple registries with same port as i am working in a docker image that exposes port 9759 and tried this :

```
class JenkinsCollector:
 def __init__(self, jenkinsInstances):
//some code
  **@app.route('/collectormetrics')**
 def collect(self):
//some code of gauge metric
class pollScm:
 def __init__(self, jenkinsInstances):
//some code
 **@app.route('/pollmetrics')**
 def collect(self):
//some code of gauge metric
if __name__ == '__main__':
 if  environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/collectormetrics':
        registrynode = CollectorRegistry()
        registrynode.register(JenkinsCollector(
          jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
        start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registrynode)
      elif environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/pollmetrics':
        registryscm = CollectorRegistry()
        registryscm.register(pollScm(
          jenkinsInstances=jenkinsInstances ))
        start_http_server(port=9759,registry=registryscm)
```

But it didn't work !! i need a way to let both exporter registries use same port but use different path ('/') so that the server can invoke the request with same port but depends on the route path to guess what metric should display!

i'm thankfulll

Comment: This is not going to work with `start_http_server`, which comes from the prometheus_client library. It seems that you have also defined routes in Flask (?), so you should build a fully-fledged Flask application instead. You can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this with Twisted:
first install twisted with: `pip install twisted` and `pip install prometheus-client` of course

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from prometheus_client import REGISTRY, CollectorRegistry, Gauge
from prometheus_client.twisted import MetricsResource
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from random import randrange

INTERVAL = 5.0
PORT = 8000

# create first registry
registry1 = CollectorRegistry()
a = Gauge("bla1", "bla documentation", registry=registry1)

# create second registry
registry2 = CollectorRegistry()
b = Gauge("bla2", "bla2 documentation", registry=registry2)

# function will be called every INTERVAL
def update():
    b.set(randrange(10))
    a.set(randrange(10))

root = Resource()
# set path for first registry
root.putChild(str.encode('path1'), MetricsResource(registry1))
# set path for second registry
root.putChild(str.encode('path2'), MetricsResource(registry2))

factory = Site(root)
# create loop to call update() every INTERVAL in seconds
loop = task.LoopingCall(update)
loop.start(INTERVAL)
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.run()
```

visit `localhost:8000/path1` and `localhost:8000/path2` to see results.
values will update every 5 seconds.